# Unable to find ConfigurationErrorsException nuget package or assembly .net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to use **ConfigurationErrorsException** in a .net Core 2.2 application.
I checked the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationerrorsexception?view=netcore-2.2, but I cannot figure out which NuGet package I need to install in order to be able to use this class, if any.
Even using the fully qualified name (*System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException*) I cannot resolve the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager**
I checked the assembly names in the documentation and when I used that as search key I found this NuGet package.